# The existence of the vectors which don't satisfy the linear transformation $f: V \to V'$, $f(u_i)=v_i$ for every $i \in \{1,...,n\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> **My problem**: Let $V$, $V'$ be the vector spaces and $M=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\}$ generates $V$ but it isn't its basis. Show the
>   existence of the vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ which don't satisfy  the
>   linear transformation $f: V \to V'$, $f(u_i)=v_i$ for every $i \in
>  \{1,...,n\}$.

**My solution**: If $N=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_k\}$ would be a basis of $V$,  $k \lt n$, then $f(u_i)=v_i$ for every $i \in \{1,...,k\}$,it would work, but we can choose some vectors from $M$ for which it wouldn't work. I just don't know how. Like the remaining vectors from $M$: $\{v_{k+1},...v_n\}$ can be written as the linear combinations of the vectors from $N$ so those vectors can't be mapped "uniquely"?

Any suggestions? I really don't know and sorry for my English.

Comment: You’re on the right track. Since you have more vectors than $\dim V$, but they span $V$ , there’s some subset of them that does form a basis. The rest of the vectors can be written as linear combinations of them. What must the value of $f(u_i)$ be for those “extra” vectors for $f$ to be linear?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. As I read it, it seems trivial. You just want to show there exist values $v_i$ such that $v_i \ne f(u_i)$? If $V' \ne 0$, then that is easy. $V'$ is infinite, but $n$ is finite, so there must be vectors in $V'$ that are not equal to any $f(u_i)$ Linearity of $f$ is not required.

Comment: So how could I properly prove it please?